# Selected Item Displayed in Label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a drop down that gets product information and is populated through stored procedure. I am trying to have the selected product display in a label, so when a user chooses one product and goes to another it will display each item when my gridview has been populated. Everything works fine except my label! It currently displays "Please select a Product" but never changes.

```
If DS.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    ProdNames.DataSource = DS  ' ProdNames is the dropdown
    ProdNames.DataBind()
    ProdNames.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Please Select A Product--", "0"))

    desc = ProdNames.SelectedItem.Text
    Product.Text = "Product: " & desc & "" 'Product is my label name. 
End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this in a web application or in desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to set this when the list is bound. You'll need to change the label text when the selected index of the drop down is changed.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ProdNames" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:Label ID="Product" runat="server" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
Private Sub ProdNames_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ProdNames.SelectedIndexChanged

If ProdNames.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

Product.Text = ProdNames.SelectedItem.Text

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, after looking at your suggestion I found when I moved it everything was fine. Oh those simple ones drive me nuts! Thanks again!